# Dont change index in Jquery

Tags: jquery, indexing, each

I create a page with map, and I need to paste Bus Stops on the map.
I create a busA and busB arrays with X and Y coordinates.
But when I want to create a ".bus-stop" elements with coordinates (busstop0 with busA0, busB0; busstop1 with busA1, busB1...) all bus-stops have a default style, just the last bus-stop has a last busA and busB coordinates.

```
var busA, busB, i;
busA = [150, 250, 350];
busB = [200, 300, 400];

$.each(busA, function(index){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".scale1").prepend($('<div class="bus-stop"><div class="stop-info"></div></div>'));
        $(".bus-stop").eq(index).css({'top': busA[index] + 'px', 'left': busB[index] + 'px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the elements with jQuery and add the styles during creation

```
$(function() {
    var busA = [150, 250, 350];
    var busB = [200, 300, 400];

    $.each(busA, function(index, bus){
        $(".scale1").prepend(
            $('<div />', {
                'class' : 'bus-stop',
                css     : {
                    position: 'relative',
                    top  : bus + 'px',
                    left : busB[index] + 'px'
                }
            }).append(
                $('<div />',  {
                    'class' : 'stop-info'
                })
            )
        );
    });
});
```